# ASP.NET Core problem with background and white borders in body

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I wanted this ASP.NET Core page to look similar, but I don't know why there are still white borders on it.
[Screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HBvgB-rpZCJ4MhVHawgpv5SKIaAOWJRE/view?pli=1)

`index.cshtml`:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}
<div class="no-margins">
    <div class="text-center">
        <video autoplay muted loop id="video-bg">
            <source src="https://cdn.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/items/534380/36d92e465af833290ff1def5b2de70c8c534a81d.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <div class="content">
            <h1>Vítam vás. Táto stránka je o mne. <br> Poukazuje na to čo mám rád a kto som.</h1>
            <p>Ďakujem za návštevu.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`Site.css`:

```
html {
  font-size: 14px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  html {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}
.btn:focus, .btn:active:focus, .btn-link.nav-link:focus, .form-control:focus, .form-check-input:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.1rem white, 0 0 0 0.25rem #258cfb;
}

html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.navbar-light.bg-white {
    background-color: #212529 !important; 
}

.navbar-light .navbar-brand,
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link,
.navbar-light .navbar-toggler-icon,
.navbar-light .navbar-text {
    color: #ffffff !important; 
}

.navbar-light .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover,
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus,
.navbar-light .navbar-text a:hover,
.navbar-light .navbar-text a:focus {
    color: #cccccc !important; 
 }
.social-icons img {
    width: 15px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.logo {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.logo img {
        margin-right: 10px;
        height: 50px;
 }
.body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.no-margins {
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
.video-bg {
    padding-left: 0px !important;
    padding-right: 0px !important;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    min-width: 100vw;
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -1;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 25%;
    transform: translate(-30%, -50%);
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 100;
    color: white;
    max-width: 70%;
}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    line-height: 60px;
    background-color: #212529;
    color: white;
}
```

I am looking for a solution with no white edges.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's a layout page you didn't share, you're missing the html, head, and body sections. Try this (css and div not changed):

```css
html {
  font-size: 14px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  html {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}
.btn:focus, .btn:active:focus, .btn-link.nav-link:focus, .form-control:focus, .form-check-input:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.1rem white, 0 0 0 0.25rem #258cfb;
}

html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.navbar-light.bg-white {
    background-color: #212529 !important; 
}

.navbar-light .navbar-brand,
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link,
.navbar-light .navbar-toggler-icon,
.navbar-light .navbar-text {
    color: #ffffff !important; 
}

   
.navbar-light .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover,
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus,
.navbar-light .navbar-text a:hover,
.navbar-light .navbar-text a:focus {
    color: #cccccc !important; 
 }
.social-icons img {
    width: 15px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.logo {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.logo img {
        margin-right: 10px;
        height: 50px;
 }
.body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.no-margins {
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
.video-bg {
    padding-left: 0px !important;
    padding-right: 0px !important;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    min-width: 100vw;
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -1;
    object-fit: cover;
}


.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 25%;
    transform: translate(-30%, -50%);
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 100;
    color: white;
    max-width: 70%;
}





.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    line-height: 60px;
    background-color: #212529;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div class="no-margins">
    <div class="text-center">
        <video autoplay muted loop id="video-bg">
            <source src="https://cdn.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/items/534380/36d92e465af833290ff1def5b2de70c8c534a81d.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <div class="content">
            <h1>Vítam vás. Táto stránka je o mne. <br> Poukazuje na to čo mám rád a kto som.</h1>
            <p>Ďakujem za návštevu.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```